# How to require a specific user in Apache to only be able to login from a specific IP?

Tags: apache

I'm configuring an application that manages authentication through a heavily configured version of Apache. I need to allow login of certain users only from specific IPs. I'd like to manage this through a rule of some sort in Apache, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Currently all users are allowed from all IPs

I want all users except one to be allowed from all IPs. The one user I only want to allow to authenticate if the request is coming from an integration server that has a static IP (10.X.X.X). **There will be users added over time so the rule cannot name all the specific users allowed from anywhere.**

I have researched this a lot on google and not been able to find something that can accomplish this. I'd appreciate suggestions on how to approach this problem and I am open to alternatives that I may not have considered.

Comment: Just to clarify, you basically want everybody to be able to connect to your sever without your knowing their names/IPs, but then you also have a few administrator logins who should only be allowed to login from specific IPs for security reasons?

Comment: Yes. The users will be added to over time from a corporate LDAP. Those will always be allowed to login from anywhere on the network. For the integration user I want the user only logging in from the IP of a specific server.